# CSRF token mismatch exception when change session path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In `config/session.php` I updated the `path` to `/test` and I'm using `Redis` as session driver.

Which is throwing `TokenMismatchException` when I try to login. I added log in `VerifyCsrfToken` `tokensMatch` function and I notice `$request->session()->token()` generates different token every time.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Add this line in header     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Comment: @Komal Its already there. The token mismatch came after I'm trying to change the session path. When session path is `/`, it was working

Answer (score 0):

After days of spending found out the issue. Updated `session.path` to just `test` with out the `/` and it worked.

Comment: what is test here?